# Trying to map timestamps to dates in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame `df` with a column `time` that contains timestamps and a function `from.timestamp`

```
from.timestamp = function(timestamp) {
  return(as.POSIXlt(timestamp/1e3, origin="1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT"))
}
```

that converts a timestamp to a date type. How do I modify the data frame so that all timestamps are converted to dates?

**My approach**

I'm trying the following:

```
df$time <- apply(as.array(df$time), MARGIN=1, FUN=from.timestamp)
```

The resulting column entries for `time` do not look like a date, but are rather a sequence of numbers, e.g., `1.034, 59.000, 23.000, 7.000, 5.000, 113.000, 5.000, 157.000, 1.000`.

`dput(df)` gives:

```
structure(list(time = c(1370674741034, 1372671995085, 1370847555008, 1371456058556, 1372570911379, 1371937835807)), .Names = "time", row.names = 8831395:8831400, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `as.POSIXlt` is vectorized, so `df$time <- from.timestamp(df$time)` should work.

Comment: If you want Dates, use `as.Date`.  If you want times, use `as.POSIXct`.  Don't convert to `POSIXlt` unless you need to extract a component (hours, minutes, etc.)  Don't use `POSIXlt` with a `data.frame` because it is a list which is slower and uses more memory than POSIXct.

Comment: If someone could write up an answer that mentioned vectorization or `transform` and explained the behavior I observed with `apply`, that would be excellent.

Comment: @Peteris If you edited your question to include the ouput of `dput(head(df))` -- i.e. made the code in your question reproducible -- it would make it easier to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
df$time <- from.timestamp(df$time)
```

The reason you're getting the strange behaviour is because `POSIXlt` objects are actually lists, with components for year, month, day, etc. In your code, `apply` receives from `from.timestamp` a sequence of lists, which it combines into a single list. In doing so, it strips the class information from the result, which is why you saw your odd numbers. These odd numbers are actually the individual components of the POSIXlt object representing that datetime: seconds, minutes, hour, day of month, month, year, weekday, day in year.